# wait notify in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

```
class Callme {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("]");    
    }
}    

class Caller implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    Callme target;
    Thread t;
    public Caller(Callme targ, String s) {
        target = targ;
        msg = s;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        //synchronized(target){ // synchronized block
        target.call(msg);
        //}
    }
}
class Synch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Callme target = new Callme();
        Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Hello");
        ob1.t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "Synchronized");
        Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "World");
        ob2.t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        ob3.t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println(ob1.t.getPriority());
        System.out.println(ob2.t.getPriority());
        System.out.println(ob3.t.getPriority());
        // wait for threads to end
        try {
            ob1.t.wait();
            ob2.t.wait();
            ob3.t.wait();
            ob1.t.notifyAll();

        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas we give priority to child threads and `wait()` and `notifyall()` methods are used so have to run according to priority. But not run. If we use `synchronized(target)` also, then also not run according to priority.

Answer (score 3):

The `Tread.setPriority()` changes the execution priority of the thread, which means that a higher priority thread has a better chance of getting picked for execution when running (compared to a concurrently running lower priority thread).  Of course, if you stop the thread with excplicit call to `wait()`, it will not be running while waiting, so the priority is meaningless in that situation.

*Update*: as mentioned above the priority is for *running* threads.  When you call `notify()` the thread selected is not based on priority (at least it is not guaranteed to, the specification does not say one way or another)

Comment: SIR...AS ALL 3 THREADS ARE IN WAITING ....and after notifyall method...the thread who has more priority will run first or not?

Comment: There is no certainty on which thread will run first, but in general higher priority threads have a _higher chance_ of being picked for execution at any moment in time

Comment: True, although he can probably implement its own locking logic to be able to notify the "good" thread !

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the operating system the program is running on. Few operating system doesn't heed about the priority set by application -- or behave unexpectedly. Hence, one should not depend on priority.

**Similar thread found:**

[Thread priority and Thread accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413581/thread-priority-and-thread-accuracy)

Answer (score 1):

[Java Language Specification, 17.2.2 Notification:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2)

"There is no guarantee about which thread in the wait set is selected."

Take note of the carefully chosen terminology: a wait **set**.